# How to wrap long lines of Apache Camel Java DSL code

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl, intellij-plugin, code-standards

In my project we are using Apache Camel via Java DSL

This is how a typical route looks:

```
    from("direct:MyPizzaRestaurant")
            .routeId("PizzaRoute")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOG, LOG_IN_MESSAGE)
            .bean(veryImportandAndUniqueManagementService, "addTomatoesAndCheeseAndThenPutInTheOven(${in.headers.pizzaContextKey},${in.headers.httpHeaders[pizzaOrderIz]},${in.headers.httpHeaders[restaurantId]},${in.headers.httpHeaders[orderChannel]},${in.headers.customerId},${in.headers.httpHeaders[pizzaType]},${in.headers.httpHeaders[promo]})")
            .end();
```

Now what bothers me is the **line length**. It is uncomfortable to read and maintain, different code analyzing tools like SonarCube are raising warnings about that.
I want to ask **how would you wrap this line and what option would you recommend to fit this code into the 120 symbols width**?

For example you could do this:

```
        from("direct:MyPizzaRestaurant")
                .routeId("PizzaRoute")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOG, LOG_IN_MESSAGE)
                .bean(veryImportandAndUniqueManagementService,
                        "addTomatoesAndCheeseAndThenPutInTheOven(
                        "${in.headers.pizzaContextKey}," +
                        "${in.headers.httpHeaders[pizzaOrderIz]}," +
                        "${in.headers.httpHeaders[restaurantId]}," +
                        "${in.headers.httpHeaders[orderChannel]}," +
                        "${in.headers.customerId}," +
                        "${in.headers.httpHeaders[pizzaType]}," +
                        "${in.headers.httpHeaders[promo]})")
                .end();
```

The drawback of this is when you are using Apache Camel Plugin for IntelliJ, it allows you to ***quickly go inside the method implementation by Clicking on with with Ctrl***. But it only works when string parameter containing method and input params is a single line string. So in the example above you will lose the ability to quickly travel to the specified method but gain readability. Is there a way to somehow combine both?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Camel [parameter binding](https://camel.apache.org/manual/parameter-binding-annotations.html) instead ?

```
@Bean("veryImportandAndUniqueManagementService")
public ManagementServiceImpl {
  public Object addTomatoesAndCheeseAndThenPutInTheOven(
           @Header("pizzaContextKey") String ctxKey,
           @Header("custId") Long customerId, 
           etc...
         ) {
... 
}
```

Alternatively you could also define a second method to 'unwrap' Camel raw message:

```
@Bean("veryImportandAndUniqueManagementService")
public ManagementServiceImpl {
   public Object addTomatoesAndCheeseAndThenPutInTheOven(Exchange exchange) {
    return this.addTomatoesAndCheeseAndThenPutInTheOven(
     exchange.getMessage().getHeader("pizzaContextKey", String.class),
     exchange.getMessage().getHeader("custId", Long.class), 
     etc...
    );
    }
}
```

This way, the client code become much simpler:

```
from("direct:MyPizzaRestaurant")              
   .bean(veryImportandAndUniqueManagementService, "addTomatoesAndCheeseAndThenPutInTheOven")
```